# How to get a value from controller to form

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I've built a master/detail form in ExtJS4 as an exercise of learning ExtJS. 
I want to pass down `id` from master table to the `detail` form when i'm creating a new article.
When the `create` button is pressed in `detailGrid`, the `id` is passed to the `controller`.  In the `controller` I can see the output of the `id` via `console.log` so I know it is present in the `controller`.
How can I pass it to the form?

Controller:

```
{    
    var detailgrid = button.up('userdetail');      
    var parentId = detailgrid.getParentId();
    console.log(parentId);
    var view = Ext.widget('detailadd');  
},
```

The Form where I need to get `parentId` from the `controller`

```
Ext.define('calsberg.view.user.DetailsAdd', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.detailadd',
    title: 'Add Artikli',
    config:
    {
        parentId: parentId
    },
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,
    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                bodyStyle: {
                    background: 'none',
                    padding: '10px',
                    border: '0'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'parentId',
                        value: this.getParentId()
                    },
                    {                        
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'sifra',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        fieldLabel: 'Šifra'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'naziv',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        vtype: 'naziv',
                        fieldLabel: 'Naziv'
                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put the variable in the global namespace so that you can reference it from anywhere in the App e.g.

```
// MyApp would already be initialised in app.js
MyApp.parentId = detailgrid.getParentId();

// then you could reference it anywhere else thereafter
Ext.define('calsberg.view.user.DetailsAdd', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.detailadd',
    title: 'Add Artikli',
    config:
    {
        parentId: MyApp.parentId
    }
.....
```

Or you could pass in a config object when you create the widget such as this

```
var detailgrid = button.up('userdetail');      
var parentId = detailgrid.getParentId();
console.log(parentId);
var view = Ext.widget('detailadd', {config:{parentId:parentId}});
```

Comment: When you pass the config object how do you call it in the form.
I still get false in textbox when i try to view what's written.

Comment: Inspect your `this` and see where you're configs are in the properties.